# windows 8 local html file as background

Tags: windows-8, html, desktop-customization

As far as i can tell, windows officially removed option to set web page and/or local html as desktop wallpaper, when win vista was released.. Personally i, as web developer, totally loved this feature. And i was sad, when i found out that my windows 8 can't do this anymore.

I understand, that MS did this for security reasons.. but still, i wanted to know, is there some way to make a LOCAL html file as a wallaper in windows 8, or can i make some sort of live wallpaper with web languages..?

If someone knows anything, that could be close, to what i want to achieve, please let me know..

Just for reference, i have: windows 8.1 64bit and i have access to SuperUser

Comment: Why are you stating you have access to SuperUser? If you hadn't, how would you have written this?

Comment: what I meant was,  I have the access to superuser in windows (it means my user can bypass the windows account control).  And I wrote that here,  cos maybe some solution needs something like that..

Answer (score 0):

Would be nice to comment as I am not 100% sure this will meet your needs but apparently I need 50rep.
There is a program called Wallpaper Webpage, my friend used(uses) it on his windows 7 64bit machine years back. I did a quick google of it, and it shows compatible with windows7 with no mention of 8(which wasn't out at the time). So I would suggest giving that a shot.

Comment: well, the app works on windows, but it dosn't quite do, what i would like.. It dosnt show dekstop icons, would be the biggest issue..